# print array using map return undefined

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

i hava an array like this

```
const HeaderData = [
  {
    header: {
      title: "How you`ll benefit",
      detail:
        "We create this goals to help you recover from your recent surgery. Slowly increase your physical strength is an important part of recovery. With this plan, you will be back to normal in no time. You got this!",
    },
  },
  {
    mainData: {
      title: {
        CreatedOn: "Created on",
        CreatedBy: "Created by",
        Started: "Started",
        Completed: "Completed",
      },
      detail: {
        CreatedOn: "4/1/2021",
        CreatedBy: "Jennifer O",
        Started: "4/1/2021",
        Completed: "In progress",
      },
    },
  },
]
```

Now i want to print out `title` data in `mainData` , i use this

```
export const GoalDetail = observer(function GoalDetail() {
  const SCREEN_MARGIN: ViewStyle = {
    margin: 15,
  }
  return (
    <Screen preset="scroll" style={SCREEN_MARGIN}>
      <View>
        <Text preset="h3">{HeaderData[0].header.title}</Text>
        <Text preset="h4">{HeaderData[0].header.detail}</Text>
      </View>
      <View row>
        <View>
          {HeaderData.map((item, key) => (
            <Text key={key}>{item.mainData.title}</Text>
          ))}
        </View>
      </View>
    </Screen>
  )
})
```

But emulator show me this
Please help, what wrong with my code?? Thank you a lots

[image]

Comment: It's pretty clear that `mainData` doesn't exist on `HeaderData[0]`. This structure doesn't make a whole lot of sense -- some context about why you're using it in the first place would be nice. Maybe you want `HeaderData.slice(1).map`?

Comment: No, this part work file, i have problem in array

Comment: https://ibb.co/qRzhSxT here, if i comment the array

Comment: Only the second element of your HeaderData array has a `mainData` property so its going to error out on the first element since it doesnt have `mainData`. Use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out elements that do not have that property before mapping them

Comment: @ggorlen i will try right now and report to you, please help, i'm pretty new

Comment: @PatrickEvans , so basic, it loop for all data, how can i make `map` only loop for element i want, for example `title`?

Comment: or how can i only loop for `maindata`?

Comment: @LêQuốcKhánh Can you help me understand what is it that you are trying to achieve?.

Comment: I want to get `mainData.tilte` value,  @nithinpp

Comment: The answer from @jasonmzx will filter out the items with `mainData` property available. Which then will have the property `title`. The `title` property here is an object, and you are trying to display an object with `Text` component. If you want to display any specific property of an object, you can do so by using ` . ` operator. For example, to display the text `created On`, you can use `item.mainData.title.CreatedOn`. Is there any particular reason you are using the given data structure?

Comment: But i want to show all date on title at the same time, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
(HeaderData.filter(elm => elm.mainData)).map( (item,key) => (
    console.log(item.mainData.title)
));
```

Basically, only one of your array elements has the mainData key, meaning the first one will be undefined since it doesn't, simply filter all elements in the array which have the key: mainData then map that..

Solution above

- It works with console.log, so you can easily replace that with react logic.

Try:

```
<View>
{(HeaderData.filter(elm => elm.mainData)).map( (item,key) => (
  <Text key={key}>{item.mainData.title}</Text>
))}
</View>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but maybe it missing something ? i have error like this https://ibb.co/HVM0tWv

Comment: @Horst so how can i loop through this, please help

Comment: you might use `Object.keys(item.mainData.title)` to get the keys in array form. or loop it with `for...in` statement like the ans below.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `filter`, just `map` them:

```js
HeaderData.map((item, key) => {
   if (item?.mainData?.title)
      return renderTitle(item.mainData.title, key)
   else
      return null; // This mean show nothing, the same with return ""
})
```

Somewhere inside the component, declared a function:

```js
const renderTitle = (title, idx) => {
   // title is object
   let result = [];
   for (const key in title)
      result.push(<Text key={idx}>{title.key}</Text>)
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but i got this error as @jsonmxz answer, it return object like `createOn` `cretaeby` but not return these value, how can i return value?

Comment: You need another function to render them, updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry for late update, but i think i will use tranditional way